# Merging shapefiles with rasters

Tags: raster, arcmap, shapefile, merge, pipe-network

I'm using ArcMap, I have a shapefile which is my wastewater pipelines, now I need to merge some rasters which are about ground movement and groundwater table with this shape file to know what is the ground situation of each pipe. How can I merge all these together? Should I change pipelines to points and then merge them to other rasters?

Comment: I think the tool you're after is Sample https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z0000002v000000 which requires the spatial analyst extension or Zonal Statistics as Table https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000w8000000 which also requires spatial analyst.

Comment: If you have a basic license you could convert your rasters to polygons and then run an overlay/spatial join of them with your shapefile.

Comment: The problem is solved by converting the raster to point and then using a spatial join for merging the tables.